# How to extract only the entries with values from a python dataframe after splitting it over comma

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

How to extract only the entries with values from a python dataframe after splitting it over comma?

[image]

In this example, for row 0 I want columns 1,2,3 but for row 1 I want columns 2,3,4, i.e. the three columns that I extract should be the last three entries of the dataframe row (excluding None)

Here is what I did

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pathlib import Path

filepath = Path("/home/anand/Downloads/Python Test/Python Test/data/input/test_addresses.csv")

def extract_address_components(filepath):
    mms = pd.read_csv(filepath) 
    mms.fillna(0, inplace=True)
    addr = mms['Address'].str.split(',', expand=True)
    mms['Locality'] = addr.apply(loca, axis=1)
    mms['City'] = addr.apply(cit, axis=1)
    mms['State'] = addr.apply(sta, axis=1)
    return mms

def loca(x):
    if x.last_valid_index() is None:
        return np.nan
    else:
            return x[x.last_valid_index()-2]

def cit(x):
    if x.last_valid_index() is None:
        return np.nan
    else:
        return x[x.last_valid_index()-1]

def sta(x):
    if x.last_valid_index() is None:
        return np.nan
    else:
        return x[x.last_valid_index()]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mms = extract_address_components(filepath=filepath)
    mms.to_csv('/home/anand/Desktop/address_components.csv')
```

Is there a better way using pandas?

Comment: Can you share your attempt?

Comment: Can you show us the original file data? I think it's better to do this before the data are transformed in Dataframe.

Comment: MMS_ID Address
1 Near Wagheshwar Temple, Wagholi, Pune, Maharashtra
2 Magarpatta, Pune, Magarpatta, Pune, Maharashtra
3 Manikbaug Sinhgad Road Pune, Sinhgad Road, Pune, Maharashtra
4 Kothrud, Pune, Maharashtra
5 Pimple Nilakh, Pune, Maharashtra
6 Opposite To D Mart And Next To Cybage It, Kalyani Nagar, Pune, Maharashtra
7 Pune, Pimple Nilakh, Pune, Maharashtra
8 Flat No15 , 2nd Floor, Near Jakat Naka,Pune, Bekrai Nagar, Pune, Maharashtra
9 Wagholi, Pune, Maharashtra
10 Wakad Near Euro School, Shankar Kalat Nagar, Pune, Maharashtra

Comment: MMS_ID Address
1 Near Wagheshwar Temple, Wagholi, Pune, Maharashtra 
2 Magarpatta, Pune, Magarpatta, Pune, Maharashtra

Comment: @ScottMcC Hi, I have done it using last_valid_index() by defining a function as
def loca(x):
 if x.last_valid_index() is None:
  return np.nan
        else:
                 return x[x.last_valid_index()-2]

and calling it as

mms = pd.read_csv(filepath)
mms.fillna(0, inplace=True)
addr = mms['Address'].str.split(',', expand=True)
mms['Locality'] = addr.apply(loca, axis=1)

But I wanted a better approach in pandas. How can I do it better?

Comment: @Neabfi Hi, I have done it using last_valid_index() by defining a function as def loca(x): if x.last_valid_index() is None: return np.nan else: return x[x.last_valid_index()-2] and calling it as mms = pd.read_csv(filepath) mms.fillna(0, inplace=True) addr = mms['Address'].str.split(',', expand=True) mms['Locality'] = addr.apply(loca, axis=1) But I wanted a better approach in pandas. How can I do it better?

Comment: Don't put your attempts in the comments, put it in your original question

Comment: @ScottMcC - Yes, I have added my approach in the question. Can you tell me a better approach to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension:

```
import pandas as pd

num_cols = 3
clean_data = []

data = [["Near Wagheshwar Temple", "Wagholi", "Pune", "Maharashtra", None, None],
        ["Magarpatta", "Pune", "Magarpatta", "Pune", "Maharashtra", None],
        ["Manikbaug Sinhgad Road Pune", "Sinhgad Road", "Pune", "Maharashtra", None, None],
        ["Kothrud", "Pune", "Maharashtra", None, None, None],
        ["Pimple Nilakh", "Pune", "Maharashtra", None, None, None],
        ["Opposite To D Mart And Next To Cybage It", "Kalyani Nagar", "Pune", "Maharashtra", None, None],
        ["Pune", "Pimple Nilakh", "Pune", "Maharashtra", None, None],
        ["Flat No15 ", "2nd Floor", "Near Jakat Naka,Pune", "Bekrai Nagar", "Pune", "Maharashtra"],
        ["Wagholi", "Pune", "Maharashtra", None, None, None],
        ["Wakad Near Euro School", "Shankar Kalat Nagar", "Pune", "Maharashtra", None, None]]

for row in data:
    y = [a for a in row if a is not None]
    clean_data.append(y[-num_cols:])

labels = ["Locality", "City", "State"]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(clean_data, columns=labels)
```

```
print(df)

              Locality  City        State
0              Wagholi  Pune  Maharashtra
1           Magarpatta  Pune  Maharashtra
2         Sinhgad Road  Pune  Maharashtra
3              Kothrud  Pune  Maharashtra
4        Pimple Nilakh  Pune  Maharashtra
5        Kalyani Nagar  Pune  Maharashtra
6        Pimple Nilakh  Pune  Maharashtra
7         Bekrai Nagar  Pune  Maharashtra
8              Wagholi  Pune  Maharashtra
9  Shankar Kalat Nagar  Pune  Maharashtra
```

Comment: Hi ukemi. Thanks for your answer. But for your case I first need to convert the dataframe into a list of lists. Can it be done on the dataframe itself??

Comment: my data is in a dataframe. Your procedure talks about list of lists. So is there a way to directly do it on a dataframe?

Comment: @Anand Nautiyal your data is in a CSV file. I'm suggesting you import it first as a list in order to clean it and *then* convert it into a dataframe.

Comment: Okay I have converted my data into a list and processed it. Also got the required three columns. But now I have merge this df back to the data I had. How can I merge it without having a common column in both the dataframes by only using pandas??

Comment: What I did is 
df['MMS_ID'] = range(1, len(df) + 1)

since my original data contains "MMS_ID" column starting at 1. Is this okay or there is a better approach?